# Cordova startWith Methode not working on old mobiles

Tags: android, cordova

I used the Methode startsWith, which is only working on Android 5 and above.

```
if(array[var].startsWith("code"))
```

Is there another easy way to do this, so that its also working on Android 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startsWith` is not a cordova method, is a javascript method. It will deppend on the support of the webview

Here you can see browser support
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Note that it says:

- "Android" -> No support.
- "Chrome for Android" -> 36

On Android 5 the webview is based on chromium and updatable, right now it uses the version 48, so it supports the `startsWith`

On the link you have a polyfill, so you can use it with previous versions

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position){
      position = position || 0;
      return this.substr(position, searchString.length) === searchString;
  };
}
```